# How do I obtain an array of all the docs in my model?

Tags: mongoose

myModel.find({}, function(err, models){

console.log(models.toJSON());      //Error: object has no toJSON method

})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it, but you need to use JSON.stringify() instead of toJSON():

```
myModel.find({}, function(err, models){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(models));
})
```